# Set function $f:X^2\to\mathcal{P}_{2}$ defined as $f:(x,y)\mapsto \{x,y\}$, surjectivity and its inverse's cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $P_2$ the set which its elements are the subsets of $X$ with 1 or 2 elements. Let

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}f&:&X^2&\to&\mathcal{P}_{2}\\&&(x,y)&\mapsto&\{x,y\}.\end{array}$$

1. Show that $f$ is surjective.
2. Let $Y\in \mathcal{P}_2$. Determine $f^{-1}(\{Y\})$ and its cardinal in terms of the cardinal of $Y$.

---

1. If $\{x,y\}\in \mathcal{P}_2=\{Y\subset X : \text{card}(Y)\in[1;2]\}$ and $(x,y)=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$, therefore $\{x,y\}\in(x,y)\in X^2$ so for all $\{x,y\}\in \mathcal{P}_2$ there is $(x,y)\in X^2$ such that $f(x,y)=\{x,y\}$ thus $f$ is surjective.
2. If $x=y$ therefore $Y=\{x,y\}=\{x\}$ and $\text{card}(Y)=1$ thus $\text{card}(f^{-1}(\{Y\}))=1$.

I'm not sure how to go through $x\neq y$ (so $\text{card}(Y)=2$). I also think my reasoning overall is insufficient, so I would appreciate some advice, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For $f$ is surjective, it is correct, but I think it should be a bit "clearer", something like this: Given an $\{x,y\}\in\mathcal{P}_2$ and having $x\in\{x,y\}$, construct $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}=(x,y)\in X^2$. The case of $\{x\}\in\mathcal{P}_2$ is a special case of $\{x,y\}\in\mathcal{P}_2$, only with $x=y$ so that $\{x\}=\{x,x\}$. Hence, for all $z\in\mathcal{P}_2$ there exist $w\in X^2$ such that $f(w)=z$. Hence, $f$ is surjective.
2. For $x=y$, $f^{-1}(\{x,y\})=\{\{x\},\{x,x\}\}=\{\{x\},\{x\}\}=\{\{x\}\}$ and $\{\{x\}\}$ has only $1$ element -- $\{x\}$ (*NOT* $x$ ; this is a bit tricky when I first encountered this as student).
3. For $x\neq y$, $f^{-1}(\{x,y\})=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$. Apply Extensionality to have $\{x\}\neq \{x,y\}$. Hence $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ has $2$ elements.